Question on Journey Builder recurring schedule send
We have setup one recurring Journey in Salesforce Marketing Cloud for everyday(Sun-Sat) 11 am IST.
The entry source is data extension which is keep updating multiple times in a day. If someone updates the data multiple times in the DE, will it also affect the Journey.
I am not sure if someone updates the Data in the Data Extension multiple times in a day. Will SFMC send email every members of the DE or only those members that have been evaluated at 11 AM IST at the time of Journey run.

If I understand correctly, then this is a setting you find in the Journey Entry Event's schedule. (evaluate new records only vs. evaluate all records). Meaning both options exist, you can just click the schedule and check.

